# Calling base functions through member function pointers

Tags: c++, polymorphism, pointer-to-member

Consider this small program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual void say_hello() {
        std::cout << "Hello from Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    void say_hello() override {
        std::cout << "Hello from Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Derived d;

    d.Base::say_hello();          // prints "Hello from Base"
    (d.*(&Base::say_hello))();    // prints "Hello from Derived"

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and executed, it prints:

```
Hello from Base
Hello from Derived
```

As far as I understand, objects of both the `Base` and `Derived` classes are polymorphic objects and somehow contain runtime type information. That way the right overridden function can be choosen even if for base class pointers pointing to a derived object. I also learned that the overridden function from the baseclass is still available and can be called with an explicit call like:

```
object.Base::function()
```

In the small program above we can see, that this indeed works as expected. The `say_hello` method from the base class is selected in the `d.Base::say_hello()` expression and prints `"Hello from Base"`.

What puzzles me now:

- Why does the second case not call the base class method?
- Is there a way to call the base member function through a member function pointer?
- And is there even a difference between the following two expressions?

  ```
  &Base::function
  &Derived::function
  ```

Comment: [\[conv.mem\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/conv.mem#2).

Comment: The reference of @dfrib gives the answer to bullet 1 and 3. It is not (easily) found  in the duplicate references.

Comment: Regarding point 3, one important difference is that `&Derived::function` can't be used with a `Base*`.

Comment: One solution is to add a second function which is not `virtual` which stores the implementation and have the `virtual` forward the call to the non-`virtual` one. Alternatively you can store a `std::function` with a lambda that does the call to the specific override you want.

Comment: @dfrib thanks for the reference. I had to read it a couple of times and still have the feeling that I understood only half of the paragraph. I think the core statement is this one: *The result is the same as if indirecting through the pointer to member of B with the B subobject of D*. But doesn't that mean, that the call should be done like with a B object (which would call the base method)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the question was closed before I could post my answer explaining the reference of @dfrib. Note this sentence: *The result refers to the member in D's instance of B* and *The result is the same as if indirecting through the pointer to member of B with the B subobject of D*. Hence, to call the base function, the object pointer must be casted to base type as in `((Base)d.*(&Base::say_hello))();`. On the other hand, `((Base)d.*(&Derived::say_hello))();` will fail since the pointer `&Derived::say_hello` does not belong to `Base`.